# Puppeteer how to check if page is navigated and perform task if not navigated

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, puppeteer, browser-automation

On the login page, I'm trying to figure out whether the google recaptcha appears or not. If it does, I want to run a block of code and otherwise navigate as usual.

```
await page.goto(
    url
  );
  await page.waitForSelector("#username");
  await page.type("#username", process.env.EMAIL);
  await page.type("#password", process.env.PSWD);
  await  page.$eval("#signIn > div > button", (el) => el.click()) //this line sometimes triggers recaptcha

  {//here wait for navigation and check if google captcha appears}

  //then run the following code:
  await page.solveRecaptchas();
  await Promise.all([
    page.waitForNavigation(),
    page.click("#signIn"),
  ]);
```

I've tried using page.waitForNavigation but it causes timeout if recaptcha appears. What can I do to run the bottom block of code ONLY if google recaptcha appears?

I also tried conditionally running the block of code on if `recaptcha-token` is present but I checked the dom and recaptcha element is always present and only prompts image select randomly. Basically I'm available to navigate sometimes without having to perform any captcha and sometimes i'm prompted with image select.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Maybe something like this?

```js
const [_, navigation] = await Promise.allSettled([
  element.click(),
  page.waitForNavigation(),
]);

if (navigation.status === 'fulfilled') /* There was navigation. */;
else /* There was timeout, no navigation. */;
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Though, I'd rather not have it wait for timeout because it's a bot that needs to be fast and efficient. Is it possible to lower the timeout?

Comment: Yes, there are parameter and default property for this: [`page.waitForNavigation()`](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/docs/api.md#pagewaitfornavigationoptions)

Comment: Oh okay, mind sharing some tips on how pass that option parameter to waitForNavigation?

Comment: I think it is `page.waitForNavigation({ timeout: 5000 })` for 5 sec.

Comment: Hey, @vsemozhebuty where did you get that "fulfilled"? I don't see it in the docs and neither can reproduce it https://pptr.dev/#?product=Puppeteer&version=v8.0.0&show=api-pagewaitfornavigationoptions
Thank you!

Comment: @scythargon It is not a puppeteer feature, it is a resent language feature: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/allSettled